error after upgrading to angular 16 from angular 13
I have upgraded my angular project to angular 16 from angular 13 step by step. There are certain pipes which i have used in the project like for example translate pipe. When i am serving the project now i am getting multiple errors of pipe not found and cant bind to nbmodel since it is not a known property of input. i have also tried removing node modules and install it. I am constantly getting error like this-
No pipe found with name 'translate'.
Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
what is the problem I am not getting?
The error that i am facing is below-
No pipe found with name 'translate'.
example of pipe usage in code-
{{'_AVERAGE_HANDLING_TIME_' | translate}}"
I have translate pipe which i have imported to pipes module and pipes module is imported in shared module and share module is imported in app module
pipes.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePipe } from './translate.pipe';
import { SafePipe } from './safe.pipe';
import { DashboardSearchPipe, GenderTextPipe, SuggestionSearchPipe, TaskTemplateSearchPipe, TemplateTypePipe, WallboardSearchPipe } from './custome.pipe';

@NgModule({
    exports: [
        TranslatePipe,
        SafePipe,
        TemplateTypePipe,
        SuggestionSearchPipe,
        TaskTemplateSearchPipe,
        DashboardSearchPipe,
        GenderTextPipe,
        WallboardSearchPipe
    ],
    declarations: [
        TranslatePipe,
        SafePipe,
        TemplateTypePipe,
        SuggestionSearchPipe,
        TaskTemplateSearchPipe,
        DashboardSearchPipe,
        GenderTextPipe,
        WallboardSearchPipe
    ],
    providers: [
        TranslatePipe,
        SafePipe,
        TemplateTypePipe,
        SuggestionSearchPipe,
        TaskTemplateSearchPipe,
        DashboardSearchPipe,
        GenderTextPipe,
        WallboardSearchPipe
    ]
  })
  export class PipesModule { }

shared.module.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PipesModule } from '../pipes/pipes.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app.routing.module';
import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
import { AngularMaterialCommonModule } from '../angular-material-common.module';
import { DirectivesModule } from '../directives/directive.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        EditorModule,
        TagInputModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AngularMaterialCommonModule,
        PipesModule,
        DirectivesModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        EditorModule,
        TagInputModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AngularMaterialCommonModule,
        PipesModule,
        DirectivesModule
    ],
})
export class SharedModule { }

app.module.ts
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TINYMCE_SCRIPT_SRC } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { nlLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuditLogComponent } from './auditlog/auditlog.component';
import { CaseSearchResultComponent } from './case/casesearchresult.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './common/aboutus.component';
import { AppLoaderComponent } from './common/apploader.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './common/auth.guard';
import { HeaderComponent } from './common/header.component';
import { LinkUnlinkEntityComponent } from './common/linkunlinkentity.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './common/login.component';
import { MessageBoxComponent } from './common/messagebox.component';
import { ProgressBarComponent } from './common/progress-bar.component';
import { SearchPopupComponent } from './common/searchpopup.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { DashboardConfigComponent } from './dashboardconfig/dashboardconfig.component';
import { DashboardWebpartComponent } from './dashboardconfig/dashboardwebpart.component';
import { DocumentSearchResultComponent } from './document/documentsearchresult.component';
import { EmployeeSearchResultComponent } from './employee/employeesearchresult.component';
import { FileSearchResultComponent } from './fileentity/fileentitysearchresult.component';
import { LinkSearchResultComponent } from './link/linksearchresult.component';
import { NewsSearchResultComponent } from './news/newssearchresult.component';
import { NoteEntitySearchResultComponent } from './noteentity/noteentitysearchresult.component';
import { OrganizationSearchResultComponent } from './organization/organizationsearchresult.component';
import { PersonSearchResultComponent } from './person/personsearchresult.component';
import { ProductSearchResultComponent } from './product/productsearchresult.component';
import { QuestionAnswerSearchResultComponent } from './questionanswer/questionanswersearchresult.component';
import { ReportComponent } from './report/report.component';
import { LocalizeService } from './services/localize.service';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { SuggestionPanelComponent } from './suggestionpanel/suggestionpanel.component';
import { EmailTemplateComponent } from './template/emailtemplate.component';
import { TaskTemplateComponent } from './template/tasktemplate.component';
import { TemplateComponent } from './template/template.component';
import { ThemeSearchResultComponent } from './theme/themesearchresult.component';
import { TicketSearchResultComponent } from './ticket/ticketsearchresult.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { WallboardModule } from './wallboard/wallboard.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    AppLoaderComponent,
    ReportComponent,
    EmailTemplateComponent,
    AuditLogComponent,
    SuggestionPanelComponent,
    DashboardConfigComponent, 
    DashboardWebpartComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    LinkUnlinkEntityComponent,
    SearchPopupComponent, 
    FileSearchResultComponent, 
    EmployeeSearchResultComponent, 
    ThemeSearchResultComponent, 
    NoteEntitySearchResultComponent, 
    ProductSearchResultComponent, 
    QuestionAnswerSearchResultComponent, 
    LinkSearchResultComponent, 
    NewsSearchResultComponent, 
    PersonSearchResultComponent, 
    OrganizationSearchResultComponent, 
    DocumentSearchResultComponent, 
    CaseSearchResultComponent, 
    TicketSearchResultComponent,
    TemplateComponent, 
    TaskTemplateComponent,
    MessageBoxComponent, 
    ProgressBarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    WallboardModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    LocalizeService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: setupTranslateFactory,
      deps: [LocalizeService],
      multi: true
    },
    { provide: TINYMCE_SCRIPT_SRC, useValue: 'tinymce/tinymce.min.js' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

export function setupTranslateFactory(
  localizeService: LocalizeService): Function {
  return () => {
    localizeService.setLanguage().then((language) => {
      localizeService.useLanguage(language == 'nl-NL' ? 'NL' : 'EN').then(() => {
        console.log("language set as: " + language);
      });
      if (language == 'nl-NL')
        defineLocale('nl', nlLocale);
    });
  };
}

package.json
{
  "name": "decos-kcs-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^6.0.1",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
    "jlinq": "^1.0.0",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.2",
    "ngx-chips": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "spin.js": "^4.0.0",
    "tinymce": "^7.3.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "x2js": "^3.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/node": "~20.8.2",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
}


Sometimes after upgrades, dependencies are a bit fucked and not well cleaned and that generates weird errors. To be sure that it's not linked and to have a clean repo, have you tried to delete all your node modules + package lock and launched npm install?

Your package.json seems to be missing the ngx-translate package - which is assume where you wanted to get the TranslatePipe from.

I have used personalised translate pipe.

If you have any standalone component you recently added, you need to import PipesModule and CommonModule.
If that does not work, then try the below.

There is some error in one of the modules, so all the imports are breaking, what you need to do, is comment all the declaration components from the module and keep just one component, then comment out all the imports you have one by one and adding them back one by one.
By doing so, you can narrow down the problematic import, once you found that fix it and uncomment the imports and declarations.

you are saying to comment the declareations from app module. I did that you have suggested but still i am getting the error.

@Anonymous And the imports add them one by one, the problem is in the imports not on the declarations, you are commenting out the code to identify the source of the problem, its a long process but gives good results when debugging, you can also revert to your last working commit

did this but still i am not able to figure out the problem where it is breaking

@Anonymous Did the errors really not reduce when you did this?

what i have did now is i made all the components as standalone component and imported shared modules and other module in that and that solve the errors that i was getting.
